# Can value change after assignment?

Tags: c++, reference, linked-list

I'm confused about this question and don't know how to ask this.
Like if -

```
current = head;
```

if value of "head" changes later like

```
head = temp->next;
```

will the value of "current" also change?

Comment: No, it won't change.

Comment: You've not stated what `current` actually is, if it's a reference then yes it would, otherwise it just takes a copy of the value and any changes to head would not affect current

Comment: @EdChum If `current` is a reference, it can't be changed, although the thing it refers to can be.

Comment: It is from linked list where current is a pointer of Node type.

Comment: @Nick, then the answer to your original question is definitely "no".

Comment: @NeilButterworth isn't the OP asking about the value of current rather than if current the object changes, I know this is semantics but this was my understanding, still the question lacks clarity

Comment: @EdChum he asks "if the value of head changes .... will the value of current change?" As both these things are pointers, the answer is "no".

Comment: Unless `head` is the reference to `current`, but that seems unlikely. Still, this is why it's important to actually state the types of variables in your question; otherwise you get a load of guesswork and follow-up questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on the *type* of `current` (and of `head`).

For example, in:

```
Node *head = get_head_from_somewhere();
Node *&current = head;
head = head->next;
```

`current` aliases `head`, so changing `head` (advancing it to point at the next node) also affects `current`. They both always have the same value.

In fact, while they're both in scope as declared above, `assert(head == current)` will always succeed.

However

```
Node *current = head;
```

creates a new and independent pointer, which just starts life pointing at the same place as `head`. Advancing `head` won't change `current` here.

Comment: nice answer, I didn't ever use reference yet. It is very probable that @NickHill isn't using those, but it is very good to point this out.

Comment: @Useless to be very honest, I know a bit about references but I've never seen anyone using **"*&current"** like stuff. What does this actually mean?

Comment: Reading from right-to-left: `current` is a reference (`&`) to a pointer (`*`) to a Node. So in the above, it is a reference to `head`, and it will always be true that `current==head`, `&current == &head`, `current->next == head->next`, etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

the answer is **no** (unless you use [references](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html)); the value of current won't change if the value of head changes.

However; if current and head are pointers, the value they **refer** to may change. For example:

```
int a = 4;
int *a1 = &a;
int *a2 = a1; // now both pointers a1 and a2 have the same value (ie the address of integer a) AND point to the same value (4)
*a1 = 5; // change value of a using pointer a1
printf("%i\n", *a2); // will print 5 since a2 also points to integer a and its value has thus changed. The value of a2 itself has not changed though (still pointing to the address of a)
```

Comment: Hi Chris, could you please explain? I'm little confused.

Comment: @NickHill I added some explanation; I hope this helps you